# Network Security Device/Software

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, anti-virus, malware

We currently run Symantec Antivirus Corporate 10.2. The software is really easy to manage on a network but the actual virus detection isn't bad but the malware detection is crap.

We recently were infected with a email bot that got us put on some block lists. This has been resolved.

I cannot have that happen again. I would like to find a program as easy to manage as symantec that I can install on all the user's workstations as well as the servers. We run a windows 2003 domain. We have a couple 2008 test servers in the environment. Most of the workstations are xp though I am using windows 7 and symantect is not compatible with this OS... So we need a solution that would cover all those operating systems. If it could be installed on macs too that would be a bonus though not necessary at all.

This software must detect:
Viruses AND Malware

I am looking for something that combines the features in anti-malware programs like  malwarebytes or spybot with an antivirus program like symantec or AVG.

Alternatively if there is a piece of hardware that is a firewall, router, and packet inspection for virus/spam that would be the most ideal solution. I then could supplement with a piece of software that could pickup what the hardware misses.

Thank you for your suggestions.

UPDATE: I am in talks with AVG for their AVG Internet Security Business Edition.
Have others used this program? How did they find the admin panel for it?
Any suggestions for removing Symantec to install AVG?

UPDATE2: I am waiting to get AVG approved for our servers. Any input that is against this decision? Any horror stories?

Comment: Why can your desktops send mail directly to the internet?  If they can't, why didn't your mail server notice the deluge of email and do something?

Comment: The desktop was using a non standard port to send. Some of these malware use custom stacks to send mail out over already open ports.

Comment: All the custom stacks in the world don't help if you don't allow port 25 (587, etc) out from your desktops to the outside.  At that point they're sending through servers they have control of, and _those_ machines can get blacklisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with AVG. It is spectacular and great value. I prefer it over Symantec and ESET

Update as per comment Request: We ended up going with AVG Business Internet Security 9. I really enjoyed the admin console. It was fast and painless to install. Deployment was equally as simple. For the exchange server you need to install the Email Edition. We licensed 25 copies and it comes with 25 mailboxes for the Anti-Spam portion. I had an issue the other day and my reseller and AVG were able to resolve it in under 1 hour. Excellent Service so far!
I would go into pricing but that is more easily found on AVGs website.

The 25 Licenses can be applied to servers or workstations. We run it on 20 workstations and 5 servers.

Comment: If you're comfortable with it, could you share what sort of per-user/per-server pricing AVG provided?  How many clients/server total?

Answer (score 1):

We have been using Symantec Endpoint Protection 11. Release 5 (11.0.2002) Some minor glitches but much better detect rate on some of teh spyware and malware.  Easy to manage but a bit of a learning curve from SAV CE 10.X  Overall it has been pretty smooth for our 100 users in five separate offices.  You can likley get an upgrade from SAV CE

We cannot deploy the firewall easily but that would also help stop some malware.

I know some users have had issues and earlier releases had some challenges.  Release 5 seems to have addressed those issues.

Version 12 is the Small Business Edition designed for 100 users or less  [Endpoint Data Sheet](http://eval.symantec.com/mktginfo/enterprise/fact_sheets/b-endpoint_protection_ds_12836807.en-us.pdf)

Comment: Interesting. I am very hesitant to go back to symantec. What is different in 11? What additional learning was required? Is the interface and security center that different?

Comment: Interface is different and client management is different.  Setup was pretty easy and there is a migration tool.  The weakaest link for us is still users that downlaod the stuff directly.  You can lso control applications if you have a standard build. We don't and it changes almost daily so hard to manage that.

Comment: Yah I cant control these freaks. They visit malicious sites and get viruses its a nightmare... management does not want me to filter the web because they need it for research. I need a really good program that can detect these threats. AVG seems really good I feel.

Comment: I think you will find SEP 11 much better than SAV. It has a smaller footprint than SAV and some of the advanced features give better protection.  Management is very granular.  Filtering can be doone with something like Websense.  Lets then go where they want but will block infected sites and has great reporting.  Not inexpensive but well worth the price

Comment: What about 12? I am finding others online saying 11 is better than 12... Thoughts?

Comment: Version 12 is the Small Business Edition.  Designed for under 100 users and some features of the Version 11 product not available. However, it is basically teh same product.  They also preconfiure some policies and some alerts. I will edit my earlier reply with a helpful link to a PDF

Answer (score 0):

Started to use this software from ESET which has good network management interface and also the scanner isnt very CPU intensive which i have seen issues

http://www.eset.co.uk/

They are also planning on releasing versions of the software for some linux distributions and Mac's i played about with a beta version of it under ubuntu for a while and was impressed with it.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I checked them out too and I am familiar with Symantec and AVG so I would rather not get into a whole new company. I am really looking for people who have info on AVG Internet Security Business Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Symantec AV Corp is discontinued, but the follow-up product, Symantec Endpoint Protection has both AV & AM...

-Josh